# rotate imageview around its center without cutting off its edges

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I've customized imageview but its just rotating its bitmap not the whole view. I don't want to use animation because I'm dragging imageview as well so moving animated imageivew results weird, so sticking to `onDraw/draw`, plus overriding draw is nothing doing special.

```
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(rotationAngle, rotationW, rotationH);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        }
```

how can I rotate the whole view not only its bitmap??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One must check width and height of the imageview, if Height > width then at the time of rotation width must be equal to height and same with height.
2. Make width and height equal to fill_parent and then rotate/translate/scale via matrix.

Answer (score 4):

I did not get the provided answers intend here, but using

> android:clipChildren="false"

for the parent `ViewGroup`
and overriding `draw` instead of `onDraw` did the job for me

For further information see:
[Rotating imageview and its background without cropp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24985829/1885518)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with API 11, there is the following method available for each view:

```
.setRotation(float angle);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3arotation)

---

Before API 11 you could add a rotate to the main-element of your view:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
  c.save();
  c.rotate(...);
  super.onDraw(c);
  c.restore();
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between code we both posted, actually I'm doing the same thing and its working but its cutting its edges unless its on 0'/180'/360'.

Comment: But do you do it on the image view or on the complete window? You can take the main container-element and turn everything. That was my thougt :)

Comment: I've multiple imageview in relativeLayout, so user tap on any of the view and then rotate/scale that view(imageview/textview), so how can I rotate the whole layout? that's why I've customized imageview but can't rotate actual container of imageview, I can't post snap of emulator so that why you are not getting it, hope you got my point :)