# Rotating ImageView and its background without crop

Tags: android, imageview

I've been searching a lot, but I can't get a solution for my problem. I can't use `android:rotation` as I want this app to be compatible with Android API under 11 version.
My problem is something similar to this: [Rotating a view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android)

I've done this:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    Drawable d = getDrawable();
    canvas.rotate(-10, d.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2, d.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2);
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

The ImageView is part of a RelativeLayout where I place the image and some text.

But the image is cropped in the edges. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 8):

You simply have to add:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

to the parent `ViewGroup`.

For Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:clipChildren="false">
    <com.yourcompany.views.RotateImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>
```

RotateImageView:

```
public class RotateImageView extends ImageView {
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
         canvas.save();
         int height = canvas.getHeight();
         int width = canvas.getWidth();
         canvas.rotate(45, height / 2, width / 2);
         super.draw(canvas);
         canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Which provides a clean solution before API Level 11

Comment: your clip children didnt work here, rather your 300dp height did work :\

Comment: You tested it with API Level < 11? Because the answer clearly states, that ii will provide a solution for lower API Level

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your ImageView as a child view of a FrameLayout and set the FrameLayouts width and height the same as that of your ImageView. View my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16465481/2266500). Original answer relayed from a post by Pavlo Viazovskyy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528483/2266500). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response, what I finally did was a little tricky, just do some scale inside draw: canvas.scale(0.9f, 0.9f, d.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, d.getIntrinsicHeight()/2); But I'll keep in mind your option.